# Laravel Excel and print break row

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Is it possible like in old PHPExcel, to define break row for printing with Laravel-Excel?

I export multiple data with a lot of merging and I don't want to have these rows break by printer so I want to setup break row myself.

I tried:

```
setBreak( 'A10' , PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );
```

But of course it didn't work.

Comment: any help? I am also facing same issue

Comment: My setup :               $sheet->setPrintArea('A1:H300');
                $sheet->setBreak( 'A10' , \PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );